# How can I figure out Vout as a function of Vin?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, zener

I am not sure how to solve for when the diodes will be in what mode. Any help is appreciated :).

[image: Photo of Circuit]

Comment: If this is ideal, determine the turn on voltage for both diodes and create a model for \$v_{out}\$ as a function of \$v_{in}\$ for when either diode is on or off. Since you have four diodes, I figure you're going to have 4 cases. If you are trying to determine the exact solution, that's a whole different story. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and we can help.

Comment: Sure, so I am trying to solve for the conditions when D1 is off and D2 on. Therefore: Vin - 10k*Itotal <4, and I = (Vin-0.7)/20k. I get the wrong answer! Answer is Vin>8.7V

Comment: Using the ideal models you'll  have a piecewise linear transfer function. So maybe start by figuring out the points of inflection.

Comment: @Stella, Your initial equations are a small step forward. But where did the <4 come from?  Is there other information missing from your diagram?

Comment: What is the Zener voltage ?

Comment: Please edit your question. There appears to be information missing. What is the specification for D1?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what one gets for Zener diode voltage varying from 1 to 8 (test).

One can see that there are 3 parts to the curve.
First when D1 & D2 are OFF
Second when D1 is ON
Third when D2 is ON ...

Sorry, the names of diodes are swapped with OP.

[image]

Now came the time of equations, if you already have all data.